# Camel + JBoss + JPA: TransactionRequiredException: Unable to register for JTA transaction despite JTA data source

Tags: jpa, jboss, transactions, apache-camel, eclipselink

I have an application based on Apache Camel that runs on JBoss AS 7.1 application server.

In one Camel route, I let Camel read XML files, unmarshal them to JPA entity objects using JAXB, and write them to a database using the Camel jpa:// component.

However, whenever an entity is sent to a JPA endpoint, Camel gives me the following TransactionRequiredException:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: joinTransaction has been called on a resource-local EntityManager which is unable to register for a JTA transaction.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.registerIfRequired(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:2092)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:327)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.joinTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer$1.doInTransaction(JpaProducer.java:64)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer.process(JpaProducer.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:424)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:424)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:735)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:82)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:303)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What I don't understand is that JPA insists that my EntityManager is resource-local. In my persistence.xml, I've defined the data source as JTA:

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="foobar">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDS</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <!-- ... lots of entity classes omitted ... -->
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The relevant section in my applicationContext.xml is this:

```
<!-- snip -->

        <import resource="classpath:/datasource.xml"/>

        <tx:annotation-driven />

        <bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        </bean>

        <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="foobar-context" useMDCLogging="true">

            <!-- ... most routes omitted ... --> 

            <camel:route id="readXML">
                <camel:from uri="file://C:/Data/xmldir"/>               
                <camel:to uri="direct:persistProduct"/>
            </camel:route>

            <camel:route id="persistProduct">
                <camel:from uri="direct:persistProduct"/>
                <camel:unmarshal ref="tnxJAXB"/>
                <camel:to uri="jpa:com.foo.bar.Product"/>
            </camel:route>

            <!-- ... a lot of other unrelated stuff omitted ... -->

        </camelContext>

<!-- snip -->
```

For testability, the data source stuff is in another file:

datasource.xml (complete):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    ">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myDS" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="foobar"/>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

If my research online was thorough, then all this is supposed to be correct and transaction management should work.
However, it doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

The package versions I'm using:

- Camel 2.14.3
- Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE
- Eclipselink 2.6.0-M3
- JBoss AS 7.1.1-Final

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: It should default to JTA in a container environment, but it depends on how Camel is creating the context.  You can explicitly define it by adding <persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA"> to your persistence unit

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately I tried it but it didn't do anything about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occurs when you do not start a transaction. Remember transaction needs to be started at service level not at repository level. As service and repository code is not available here cannot help more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I tell Camel to start a transaction? All the database stuff happens inside the Camel JPA component. Regarding the documentation of Camel JPA, I was under the impression that Camel automatically creates transactions, unless explicitly turned off in case you use a resource local datasource - but mine isn't resource local. Why does Camel JPA think it is?